# ROS2 colcon build failure

Tags: cmake, package, ros, ros2, colcon

Win10 x64, ROS 2 - Humble, VS 2019

I'm going through the ROS beginners tutorials but I've run into problem building packages with `colcon` and got as far as the [Using colcon to build packages](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html) tutorial.

I'm running as admin from a VS 2019 command line, I sourced `ros2` by running the `local_setup.bat` file. I installed the `colcon` extensions, downloaded the examples & set up the directory structure as outlined in the tutorial.

I then tried to build `colcon` using `colcon build --symlink-install --merge-install`

Which after installing a few packages complains & aborts the build with,

```
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ROS_Humble\ros2\share\ament_cmake_core\cmake\core\package_xml_2_cmake.py", line 22, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package_string
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
CMake Error at C:/ROS_Humble/ros2/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:95 (message):
  execute_process(C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe
  C:/ROS_Humble/ros2/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/package_xml_2_cmake.py
  D:/ROS_scratch/dev/ros2_ws/src/examples/rclcpp/topics/minimal_publisher/package.xml
  D:/ROS_scratch/build/examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher/ament_cmake_core/package.cmake)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/ROS_Humble/ros2/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package_xml.cmake:49 (_ament_package_xml)
  C:/ROS_Humble/ros2/share/ament_lint_auto/cmake/ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies.cmake:31 (ament_package_xml)
  CMakeLists.txt:47 (ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies)
```

Anyone know what this is about? I've seen a few posts around about people not sourcing `ros2` in the right environment but that isn't the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

As a potential answer, for me, this issue was due to a second python installation through the Windows store that was not visible in the normal programs and applications list. After using the "newer" "Add or Remove Programs" option from Windows, I was able to find the other python installation, remove it, and was able to build.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying to obtain the `catkin_pkg` module and making sure it's installed, based on:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
```

Apparently this should do the trick: `pip install -U catkin_pkg`

---

If that doesn't help then I will update my answer with hints on how to debug this to get more information for us.

Comment: No that doesnt solve the problem when I run that I get told `catkin_pkg` is already installed

Comment: @DrBwts check permissions, i.e. if you installed it for just a single user, it might not be accessible. A clean reinstall is a guarantee in a lot of situations. Also note that you're using `C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe` python shipped with anaconda and their "custom shells" are a source of a lot of environment problems, especially if you do not open it with their shell. That being said, this is 100% a python issue. I would maybe recommend adding a `python` tag

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a local env with anaconda you should try installing the following dependencies:

```
conda install -c conda-forge catkin_pkg empy lark
```